# Buying guide for new mac

Tags: mac, adobe

My friend needs a new Mac because his current Mac is from 2011. The main thing it would be used for is Adobe Creative Cloud. He wants to edit 4k footage in Premiere Pro. Which computer would you recommend? Laptop or Desktop doesn´t matter. I have thought about the M2 Mac Mini. Would that be a good choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The M2 Mac Mini would be your only choice within budget. The base model comes with only 8Gb of RAM, and I'd recommend upgrading to at least 16Gb ($799); ideally 24Gb ($999) for your friend's uses.

They will need a keyboard, input device and display on top of that, of course; though it's possible that you may have something you can use for the time being.

They will also need more external storage for large video files, and another one for backup.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was actually thinking about recommend a M2 Mac Mini. He has many external harddrives so storage is not a problem.